# Android App read extra data on second invocation when activity is set to singleInstance

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I'm very new to Android development.

I've created an app in Java that takes extra data and simply displays a dialog box based on the extra data. So for instance the extra data could be msg="This is the message". In this case the dialog would show "This is the message".

The app is executed remotely using a command such as the following:

```
am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW  -e msg "This is the message" -n zipper.notify/.MainActivity
```

However, now I need to be able to handle the case where the application is executed again, while an instance is already running. Instead of "closing" the running instance and starting a new instance of the app I'd like to be able to simply allow only one instance of the app to run and when another instance is started just have the current instance grab the extra data and update the text shown in the dialog.

This way, the message can be updated without the application closing and then restarting.

How can this be achieved?

I've read about setting `launchMode` on the activity. If I set `launchMode` to `singleInstance` or `singleTask`, does the current running activity get some sort of message that I can handle via a method to "catch" the second invocation attempt and read the extra data?

Would the following work?

1. Set launchmode in activity to `singleTop`
2. Add the following to the activity in the onCreate() method

> ```
> getIntent().addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|
>         Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK |
>         Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
> ```

3. Handle onNewIntent()

   `protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent)
   {
       super.onNewIntent(intent);
       Log.d( "AGENT", "NEW INTENT Extra data = " + intent.getStringExtra("msg"));
   }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following seems to be working quite well. If anybody has any more to add I'd appreciate it.

1. Set `launchmode` in activity to `singleTop`
2. Add the following to the activity in the `onCreate()` method

   `getIntent().addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|
       Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK |
       Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);`
3. Handle onNewIntent()

   `protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent)
    {
       super.onNewIntent(intent);
       Log.d( "AGENT", "NEW INTENT Extra data = " + intent.getStringExtra("msg"));
    }`